# import "@ag-grid-community/csv-export";

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Hace poco me enteré que *ag-grid* actualizó sus módulos. Ahora los divide en partes para no tener que importar cosas que no utilices y hacer las aplicaciones más ligeras.

Como lo dividieron, ahora la manera de implementar `api.exportDataAsCsv` es distinta.

Antes de la actualización *22.0.1* lo hacia de esta manera y todo funcionaba bien.

```
exportDataToCSV() {
let params: any = {
  fileName: `account${moment().format()}.csv`,
  skipHeader: false,
};
this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
```

}

Pero ahora cuando lo intento, esto me dice en consola:

> ag-Grid: unable to use api.exportDataAsCSv as module
>   @ag-grid-community/csv-export is not present. You need to load the
>   module with: import "@ag-grid-community/csv-export"

Cuando voy a la documentacion [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/) dice que lo exporte como *CsvExportModule*.

Lo hago:

```
import { CsvExportModule } from "@ag-grid-community/csv-export";
```

Pero cuando intento usar sus métodos, no encuentro la menera de hacer una implementación.

[image: CsvExportModule]

Pero no encuento la manera de lograr exportar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución ya la encontre. Se las comparto:

Tal y como dice la documentación debemos exportar

> @ag-grid-community/csv-export

y debe ser exportado de esta manera

```
import { CsvExportModule } from '@ag-grid-community/csv-export';
```

Como ag-grid hizo algunas actualizaciones de como hacia la implementacion de sus modulos para no importar todo y que las aplicaciones fueran pesaras.

Ellos lo cambiaron a la manera puesta abajo.

```
export class InstructionSearchComponent implements OnInit {
      public modules: Module[] = [ClientSideRowModelModule];
...
}
```

Como el CsvExportModule es otro modulo nosotros debemos implementarlo en la lista de los modulos que el utilizara.

Un codigo completo quedaria de esta manera.

> Typescript

```
import {...} from '...';
import { CsvExportModule } from '@ag-grid-community/csv-export';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';

export class InstructionSearchComponent implements OnInit {
      public modules: Module[] = [ClientSideRowModelModule, CsvExportModule ];
...
exportDataToCSV() {
 let params: any = {
    fileName:`${fileName}.csv`,
    skipHeader: false,
 }
 this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
}
```

> HTML

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [...] [modules]="modules"></ag-grid-angular>
```

> Esto es para la version del ag grid **>= 22.0.0**